# How do you install Pygame on Mac OSX (Yosemite)

Tags: python, macos, pygame

How do you install Pygame on Mac OSX Yosemite?

Answer (score 1):

**How to Install Pygame on Mac OSX (Yosemite). Collection of combined other stack overflow answers**

1. If you want to install this under a different environment as opposed to root (always good to keep root a clean one) then after creating your environment activate it by --
   *source activate "your environment name"*
2. install homebrew
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)”
3. install xquartz11 from http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/
4. install mercurial: brew install mercurial
5. pip install: pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
   if this gives some errors related to freetype flags then first get the location of flags using

freetype-config —cflags 
(to get location of CFLAGS. is something like -*I/Users/.../.../.../.../include/freetype2*)
(use the above location)
CFLAGS='I/Users/.../.../.../.../include/freetype2' pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

6. if you want the codeskulptor equivalent then install *pip install SimpleGUICS2Pygame*